# How to query relational data using subclasses? parse.com and Unity

Tags: parse-platform, unity-game-engine

Im trying to query all elements of subclass in Unity. I have found SDK constraint or missing something here.
According to documentation querying subclasses is possible.

```
> var query = new ParseQuery<Armor>()
    .WhereLessThanOrEqualTo("rupees", ((Player)ParseUser.CurrentUser).Rupees);
query.FindAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
{
    IEnumerable<Armor> result = t.Result;
});
```

Im however using relation table and cannot specify  
Here is my code:

```
IEnumerator LoadMyDesigns(Action<RequestResult> result) {

    ParseUser user = ParseUser.CurrentUser;
    ParseRelation<Design> relation = user.GetRelation<Design>("designs");
    Task<IEnumerable<Design>> task = relation.Query.FindAsync();


    while (!task.IsCompleted) yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

    if (task.IsFaulted) {
        //error
        foreach(var e in task.Exception.InnerExceptions) {
            ParseException parseException = (ParseException) e;
            Debug.LogError("Error message " + parseException.Message);
            Debug.LogError("Error code: " + parseException.Code);
            result(new RequestResult(true, parseException.Message));
        }
    }
    else {
        result(new RequestResult(true, new List<Design>(task.Result)));
    }
}
```

And error:

> ArgumentNullException: Must specify a ParseObject class name when creating a ParseQuery.

So the question is how do I specify query subclass type when using relations?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've struggled with the same problem and in my case I needed to provide the propertyName again in de GetRelationProperty call.

For example:

```
[ParseFieldName("designs")]
public ParseRelation<Design> Designs
{
    get { return GetRelationProperty<Design>("Designs"); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try querying your designs Table.

Make a new query for class "Designs" where `equal("owner", PFUser.currentUser())`

This should return all of the designs for the current User.

Comment: This is not the issue. I can get the relations data but I cannot specify subclass I want to use. Possibly SDK constraint